# left_join gives error with three key variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am getting getting an error when I try to merge two data sets using `left_join` with three "key" variables. Here is a reproducible example:

```
df1 <- tribble(
~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4,
1, 1, 1, 4,
2, 2, 2, 5,
3, 3, 3, 6
)

df2 <- tribble(
~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var5,
1, 1, 1, 7,
2, 2, 2, 8,
3, 3, 3, 9
)

df3<- df1 %>% 
      left_join(df2, by = "var1", "var2", "var3")
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error: `suffix` must be a character vector of length 2, not string of length 
1
```

I know that `join` must be having an issue naming the key variables that are used for join, but I don't understand why.

Here is what I would like to have as a result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     4     7
2     2     2     2     5     8
3     3     3     3     6     9
```

**Solution** (thanks @user127649)

```
df3<- df1 %>% 
      left_join(df2, by = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))
```

Comment: Try: `by = c("var1", "var2", "var3")`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
df1 <- tribble(
    ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4,
    1, 1, 1, 4,
    2, 2, 2, 5,
    3, 3, 3, 6
)

df2 <- tribble(
    ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var5,
    1, 1, 1, 7,
    2, 2, 2, 8,
    3, 3, 3, 9
)

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)
```